# mysqld unknown option '--initialize'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL 5.6 on Windows Server 2012. In Linux this would have taken me 5 seconds, but I've been messing with this for hours now and I still can't log in.

I think the installer messed up at the configuration stage so I deleted the data directory and tried to recreate it:

```
bin\mysqld --initialize-insecure
```

But MySQL aborts with:

```
[ERROR] bin\mysqld: unknown option '--initialize-insecure'
```

The same happens if I use `--initialize`.

There's another error earlier in the log:

```
[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it
```

But apparently the solution to this is to run `mysqld --initialize`.

Why doesn't mysqld recognise it's own `--initialize` option?

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be found in the MySQL documentation:

> Prior to MySQL 5.7.7, Windows distributions include a data directory with prebuilt tables in the mysql database

So for MySQL 5.6, there is no `--initialize` option.